# How to re-order First Responder and ViewController in Storyboard iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

By some view, the default order is re-arranged in storyboard. What is a way to change it again to default one.

See images for clear picture.

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need to re-order them at all?

Comment: I want that, there is no issue, but when one thing changed, I must know how it happens.